# NoSQL(MongoDB) or SQL(PostgreSQL) for storing a tree/graph strucutre

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, nosql

i am in the planing phase of a project and i have the following situation:

I have an Element with a unique ID, a name and additional information.

Each Element can have multiple parents children or none. For example

Element A has no parent and three children B ,C and D (all of them are the same type like A)

Element B has one Parent (of course A) and two children E and F.

Another example would be that Element C has two parents A and B and zero or more children.

The only requirement i met is that i use to a database but i can freely choose between MongoDB or Postgresl. The Data is often read but not changed.

I believe MongoDB is the better solution. Any ideads though?

EDIT: As requested more inforamtions:

I have little experience with both, so knowledge is no argument. We are talking about less than 1500 entries right now and in the future (the next 5 years) the number of entries will not become more then 5000.

I did some research and found nested sets for sql and the mongoDB documentation for trees and i believe mongoDb comes in more handy

Comment: Why do you think MongoDB is better? What is accessing this information? Have you any experience with either MongoDB or ProgreSQL? If you do, I would probably suggest that you stick to the one you know best.

Comment: Also, what is the size of the data you expect to store? Are we talking thousands, millions or billions of elements and relations (rows)?

Comment: Check out this post for Mongo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808460/how-to-build-a-recursive-structure-with-mongodb    And this one for ProgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Added more information to the initial post

Comment: Given how little data you're talking about, about any modern database would work adequately. I'd suggest you try experimenting with both and selecting what seems to fit your needs and skills. I'm not sure why you aren't looking at graph databases.

Comment: @WiredPrairie because i have not heard of them before ;) I am investigating Neo4j, maybe this will do the job

Comment: I second WiredPrairie's suggestion about graph databases. Check Neo4j and Titan.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I have been very happy with PostgreSQL and storing trees.  `WITH RECURSIVE` gives you a good framework for traversal and navigation.  With MongoDB you are probably going to be stuck with map/reduce.

This doesn't mean there aren't a few difficulties.  These are solvable but can take some effort.  The largest is that `WITH RECURSIVE` is usually used to do breadth first searches.  You *can* do depth-first searches, but such is possible.  Note that relational databases are highly optimized for working with sets, so it is rare that a depth-first search is what you want.  In essence all your search strategies assume a set search strategy.

Graphs are more complex than trees, naturally, but there are plenty of ways to manage this.

Now, I know PostgreSQL much better than I know MongoDB but relational systems are usually more flexible in terms of query than NoSQL systems, and I would be cautious about throwing that out.